# MapBox can't add react component on markers popup

Tags: reactjs, popup, components, mapbox, marker

I have been working on a Real Estate project and I've got stuck on adding a reactcomponent inside a markers popup.
The image below shows the example of how the popup should look like:
[Popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIRMH.png)

This is the code where I am trying to add the popup on the marker:

```
var card = <Card />
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
.setDOMContent(ReactDOM.render(card, document.getElementById('map')))

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat(coordinates)
.setPopup(popup)
.addTo(map);
setMarkers(markers => [...markers, marker])
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hasn't anyone used MapBox map and had the same issue? I just want to add a component inside a markers popup but mapbox accepts only html DOM elements. Is there a way to render the component instead of DOM element?

Answer (score 2):

The expected argument type of `setDOMContent` is `Node`, but the return type of `ReactDOM.render` is `Component`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup#setdomcontent

In React, use `React.useRef` and `.current` to refer dom content.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```js
const popupRef = React.useRef(null);
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
  .setDOMContent(popupRef.current);

return (
  <>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div ref={popupRef}>popup</div>
  </>
);
```